# Why won't my method work correctly?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, while-loop, nested

I'm creating a game which has a player object `Hek` some enemy objects and the game world is a swamp. Basically the swamp can be thought of as a 4x4 grid, but the swamp size can be varied (i.e. 5x5, 6x6, 7x7, 8x8) by user input.

Within the specification, I'm working from, gives details on how `Hek` can move. `Hek` can only move to neighbouring squares, so the most squares he could pick from at one time based on a minimum of 4x4 grid is 8. The square in which he moves into is calculated at random, using `Random()`.

Below is the code I have written to simulate this, but it doesn't seem to be working really. I don't know if my while loops are being used incorrectly?

```
    public void moveHek(Hek hek) {




    boolean moveMade = false;

    while (moveMade != true) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int newMove = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
        hek.setMove(newMove);
        int x = hek.getMove();
        int prevXPos = hek.getXPosition();
        int prevYPos = hek.getYPosition();

        if (x == 1) {
            while(prevXPos > 0 && prevYPos > 0) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the top row  
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos - 1, prevYPos - 1); //and he isn't positioned within the first column of the map
                int newX = hek.getXPosition(); //and then moves Hek into the position that is diagonally left upwards to him.
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            } 
        } else if(x == 2) {
            while (prevXPos > 0) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the top row and then
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos - 1, prevYPos); //moves Hek into the position that is directly above him.
                int newX = hek.getXPosition();
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            }
        } else if(x == 3) {
            while (prevXPos > 0 && prevYPos < gameMap.length) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the top row
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos - 1, prevYPos + 1); //and he isn't positioned in the last column of the map, then moves him into the
                int newX = hek.getXPosition(); //position that is diagonally right upwards to him.
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            } 
        } else if(x == 4) {
            while (prevYPos > 0) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the first column of the map and then
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos, prevYPos + 1); //moves him into the position that is directly left.
                int newX = hek.getXPosition();
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            } 
        } else if(x == 5) {
            while (prevYPos < gameMap.length) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the last column of the map and then
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos, prevYPos - 1); //moves him into the position that is directly right.
                int newX = hek.getXPosition();
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            }
        } else if(x == 6) {
            while (prevXPos < gameMap.length && prevYPos > 0) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the last row of the map and
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos + 1, prevYPos - 1); //that his position isn't located in the first column, then moves him into the position
                int newX = hek.getXPosition(); //that is diagonally left downwards to him.
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            }
        } else if(x == 7) {
            while (prevXPos < gameMap.length) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the last row of the map and then moves
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos + 1, prevYPos); //him into the position directly below him.
                int newX = hek.getXPosition();
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            } 
        } else if(x == 8) {
            while (prevXPos < gameMap.length && prevYPos < gameMap.length) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the last row
                hek.setPosition(prevXPos + 1, prevYPos + 1); //and the last column of the map, then it moves him into the position that is diagonally
                int newX = hek.getXPosition(); //right downwards to him.
                int newY = hek.getYPosition();
                this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
                moveMade = true;
            } 
        } 
    }        
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the error that is occurring is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` and sometimes the code within the inner while loops don't even execute? Thanks!

Comment: Please specify wich line your error are. The error is caused by a newX or newY outside of the area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block:

```
    while (prevYPos < gameMap.length) { //this if while checks that Hek's position isn't located within the last column of the map and then
            hek.setPosition(prevXPos, prevYPos - 1); //moves him into the position that is directly right.
            int newX = hek.getXPosition();
            int newY = hek.getYPosition();
            this.addHek(hek, newX, newY);
            moveMade = true;
    }
```

is setting the `y` position to `prevYPos-1` without checking that `prevYPos` is greater than zero.

Also, if you are trying to avoid going over the top of an array range, you need to check that `(prevYPos + 1 < gameMap.length)` rather than `(prevYPos < gameMap.length)`